# Any easy way to upload a file to github from c#?

Tags: github, upload

I want to be able to do a simple upload of a file to a github repo in c#.net code. Anyway of doing it without setting up a local repo and doing commits?

Comment: There is a "Upload files" option in GitHub. Is this what you were looking for?